# There was an issue with the background returning the LinkedHashMap to the foreground in the wrong order

Tags: java, http

LinkedHashMap, key is a date String, value is an array of values,

For example, {" 2017-12-01 ": [1, 2, 3]," 2016-12-01 ": [1, 2, 3]," 2015-12-01 ": [1, 2, 3]}, the dates are in reverse order.

At first, the display order was fine, but then the business came up with new requirements. Instead of always displaying dates in YYYY-MM-DD format, dates were sometimes displayed in YYYY-MM or YYYY format.

Here's the kicker:

When the date format is YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM, the display sequence is normal and the background is the same. But when the format is YYYY, the order changes from backward to forward when it is returned to the foreground.

Background {" 2017 ": [1, 2, 3]," 2016 ": [1, 2, 3]," 2015 ": [1, 2, 3]} data, to the front desk becomes a {" 2015" : [1, 2, 3], "2016" : [1, 2, 3], "2017" : [1, 2, 3]}

The LinkedHashMap code I use

```
Map<String ,Object>  map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("2017",Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    map.put("2016",Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    map.put("2015",Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    return map;
```

The keys are all strings, and you can be sure that the order changes as soon as you return them, except when the key is a year.

This problem is very strange, please help to locate the cause, thank you.

Comment: This occurs when key is a pure number

Comment: "in the wrong order"? what determines the correct order? please show that code before we raise a bug for a class that is used continuously by millions of applications.

Comment: Looks like some "intelligence" triggered by number-only lists - maybe in javascript? It could also be that the map is updated so a second put is done, a kind of _update order_.